# Generating Thumnail of an Image via Windows API in HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have used the below code to create the thumbnail of an Image inside an ASP.Net application.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace RMA.Shell
{
  public class ShellThumbnail : IDisposable
  {

    [Flags]
    private enum ESTRRET
    {
      STRRET_WSTR = 0,
      STRRET_OFFSET = 1,
      STRRET_CSTR = 2
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ESHCONTF
    {
      SHCONTF_FOLDERS = 32,
      SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS = 64,
      SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN = 128,
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ESHGDN
    {
      SHGDN_NORMAL = 0,
      SHGDN_INFOLDER = 1,
      SHGDN_FORADDRESSBAR = 16384,
      SHGDN_FORPARSING = 32768
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ESFGAO
    {
      SFGAO_CANCOPY = 1,
      SFGAO_CANMOVE = 2,
      SFGAO_CANLINK = 4,
      SFGAO_CANRENAME = 16,
      SFGAO_CANDELETE = 32,
      SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET = 64,
      SFGAO_DROPTARGET = 256,
      SFGAO_CAPABILITYMASK = 375,
      SFGAO_LINK = 65536,
      SFGAO_SHARE = 131072,
      SFGAO_READONLY = 262144,
      SFGAO_GHOSTED = 524288,
      SFGAO_DISPLAYATTRMASK = 983040,
      SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR = 268435456,
      SFGAO_FOLDER = 536870912,
      SFGAO_FILESYSTEM = 1073741824,
      SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER = -2147483648,
      SFGAO_CONTENTSMASK = -2147483648,
      SFGAO_VALIDATE = 16777216,
      SFGAO_REMOVABLE = 33554432,
      SFGAO_COMPRESSED = 67108864,
    }

    private enum EIEIFLAG
    {
      IEIFLAG_ASYNC = 1,
      IEIFLAG_CACHE = 2,
      IEIFLAG_ASPECT = 4,
      IEIFLAG_OFFLINE = 8,
      IEIFLAG_GLEAM = 16,
      IEIFLAG_SCREEN = 32,
      IEIFLAG_ORIGSIZE = 64,
      IEIFLAG_NOSTAMP = 128,
      IEIFLAG_NOBORDER = 256,
      IEIFLAG_QUALITY = 512
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, Size = 0, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct STRRET_CSTR
    {
      public ESTRRET uType;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 520)]
      public byte[] cStr;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private struct STRRET_ANY
    {
      [FieldOffset(0)]
      public ESTRRET uType;
      [FieldOffset(4)]
      public IntPtr pOLEString;
    }
    [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SIZE
    {
      public int cx;
      public int cy;
    }

    [ComImport(), Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IUnknown
    {

      [PreserveSig()]
      IntPtr QueryInterface(ref Guid riid, ref IntPtr pVoid);

      [PreserveSig()]
      IntPtr AddRef();

      [PreserveSig()]
      IntPtr Release();
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("00000002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IMalloc
    {

      [PreserveSig()]
      IntPtr Alloc(int cb);

      [PreserveSig()]
      IntPtr Realloc(IntPtr pv, int cb);

      [PreserveSig()]
      void Free(IntPtr pv);

      [PreserveSig()]
      int GetSize(IntPtr pv);

      [PreserveSig()]
      int DidAlloc(IntPtr pv);

      [PreserveSig()]
      void HeapMinimize();
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("000214F2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IEnumIDList
    {

      [PreserveSig()]
      int Next(int celt, ref IntPtr rgelt, ref int pceltFetched);

      void Skip(int celt);

      void Reset();

      void Clone(ref IEnumIDList ppenum);
    }

    [ComImportAttribute()]
    [GuidAttribute("000214E6-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IShellFolder
    {

      void ParseDisplayName(IntPtr hwndOwner, IntPtr pbcReserved,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpszDisplayName,
        ref int pchEaten, ref IntPtr ppidl, ref int pdwAttributes);

      void EnumObjects(IntPtr hwndOwner,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]ESHCONTF grfFlags,
        ref IEnumIDList ppenumIDList);

      void BindToObject(IntPtr pidl, IntPtr pbcReserved, ref Guid riid,
        ref IShellFolder ppvOut);

      void BindToStorage(IntPtr pidl, IntPtr pbcReserved, ref Guid riid, IntPtr ppvObj);

      [PreserveSig()]
      int CompareIDs(IntPtr lParam, IntPtr pidl1, IntPtr pidl2);

      void CreateViewObject(IntPtr hwndOwner, ref Guid riid,
        IntPtr ppvOut);

      void GetAttributesOf(int cidl, IntPtr apidl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]ref ESFGAO rgfInOut);

      void GetUIObjectOf(IntPtr hwndOwner, int cidl, ref IntPtr apidl, ref Guid riid, ref int prgfInOut, ref IUnknown ppvOut);

      void GetDisplayNameOf(IntPtr pidl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]ESHGDN uFlags,
        ref STRRET_CSTR lpName);

      void SetNameOf(IntPtr hwndOwner, IntPtr pidl,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lpszName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ESHCONTF uFlags,
        ref IntPtr ppidlOut);
    }
    [ComImportAttribute(), GuidAttribute("BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1"), InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IExtractImage
    {
      void GetLocation([Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        StringBuilder pszPathBuffer, int cch, ref int pdwPriority, ref SIZE prgSize, int dwRecClrDepth, ref int pdwFlags);

      void Extract(ref IntPtr phBmpThumbnail);
    }

    private class UnmanagedMethods
    {

      [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      internal extern static int SHGetMalloc(ref IMalloc ppMalloc);

      [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      internal extern static int SHGetDesktopFolder(ref IShellFolder ppshf);

      [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      internal extern static int SHGetPathFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, StringBuilder pszPath);

      [DllImport("gdi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      internal extern static int DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    }

    ~ShellThumbnail()
    {
      Dispose();
    }

    private IMalloc alloc = null;
    private bool disposed = false;
    private Size _desiredSize = new Size(100, 100);
    private Bitmap _thumbNail;

    public Bitmap ThumbNail
    {
      get
      {
        return _thumbNail;
      }
    }

    public Size DesiredSize
    {
      get { return _desiredSize; }
      set { _desiredSize = value; }
    }
    private IMalloc Allocator
    {
      get
      {
        if (!disposed)
        {
          if (alloc == null)
          {
            UnmanagedMethods.SHGetMalloc(ref alloc);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          Debug.Assert(false, "Object has been disposed.");
        }
        return alloc;
      }
    }

    public Bitmap GetThumbnail(string fileName)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        return null;

      if (!File.Exists(fileName) && !Directory.Exists(fileName))
      {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The file '{0}' does not exist", fileName), fileName);
      }
      if (_thumbNail != null)
      {
        _thumbNail.Dispose();
        _thumbNail = null;
      }
      IShellFolder folder = null;
      try
      {
        folder = getDesktopFolder;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
      if (folder != null)
      {
        IntPtr pidlMain = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
          int cParsed = 0;
          int pdwAttrib = 0;
          string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
          folder.ParseDisplayName(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, filePath, ref cParsed, ref pidlMain, ref pdwAttrib);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
          throw ex;
        }
        if (pidlMain != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
          Guid iidShellFolder = new Guid("000214E6-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
          IShellFolder item = null;
          try
          {
            folder.BindToObject(pidlMain, IntPtr.Zero, ref iidShellFolder, ref item);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
            Allocator.Free(pidlMain);
            throw ex;
          }
          if (item != null)
          {
            IEnumIDList idEnum = null;
            try
            {
              item.EnumObjects(IntPtr.Zero, (ESHCONTF.SHCONTF_FOLDERS | ESHCONTF.SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS), ref idEnum);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
              Allocator.Free(pidlMain);
              throw ex;
            }
            if (idEnum != null)
            {
              int hRes = 0;
              IntPtr pidl = IntPtr.Zero;
              int fetched = 0;
              bool complete = false;
              while (!complete)
              {
                hRes = idEnum.Next(1, ref pidl, ref fetched);
                if (hRes != 0)
                {
                  pidl = IntPtr.Zero;
                  complete = true;
                }
                else
                {
                  if (_getThumbNail(fileName, pidl, item))
                  {
                    complete = true;
                  }
                }
                if (pidl != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                  Allocator.Free(pidl);
                }
              }
              Marshal.ReleaseComObject(idEnum);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
          }
          Allocator.Free(pidlMain);
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
      }
      return ThumbNail;
    }

    private bool _getThumbNail(string file, IntPtr pidl, IShellFolder item)
    {
      IntPtr hBmp = IntPtr.Zero;
      IExtractImage extractImage = null;
      try
      {
        string pidlPath = PathFromPidl(pidl);
        if (Path.GetFileName(pidlPath).ToUpper().Equals(Path.GetFileName(file).ToUpper()))
        {
          IUnknown iunk = null;
          int prgf = 0;
          Guid iidExtractImage = new Guid("BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1");
          item.GetUIObjectOf(IntPtr.Zero, 1, ref pidl, ref iidExtractImage, ref prgf, ref iunk);
          extractImage = (IExtractImage)iunk;
          if (extractImage != null)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Got an IExtractImage object!");
            SIZE sz = new SIZE();
            sz.cx = DesiredSize.Width;
            sz.cy = DesiredSize.Height;
            StringBuilder location = new StringBuilder(260, 260);
            int priority = 0;
            int requestedColourDepth = 32;
            EIEIFLAG flags = EIEIFLAG.IEIFLAG_ASPECT | EIEIFLAG.IEIFLAG_SCREEN;
            int uFlags = (int)flags;
            try
            {
              extractImage.GetLocation(location, location.Capacity, ref priority, ref sz, requestedColourDepth, ref uFlags);
              extractImage.Extract(ref hBmp);
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
            {

            }
            if (hBmp != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
              _thumbNail = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hBmp);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(extractImage);
            extractImage = null;
          }
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        if (hBmp != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
          UnmanagedMethods.DeleteObject(hBmp);
        }
        if (extractImage != null)
        {
          Marshal.ReleaseComObject(extractImage);
        }
        throw ex;
      }
    }

    private string PathFromPidl(IntPtr pidl)
    {
      StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(260, 260);
      int result = UnmanagedMethods.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);
      if (result == 0)
      {
        return string.Empty;
      }
      else
      {
        return path.ToString();
      }
    }

    private IShellFolder getDesktopFolder
    {
      get
      {
        IShellFolder ppshf = null;
        int r = UnmanagedMethods.SHGetDesktopFolder(ref ppshf);
        return ppshf;
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (!disposed)
      {
        if (alloc != null)
        {
          Marshal.ReleaseComObject(alloc);
        }
        alloc = null;
        if (_thumbNail != null)
        {
          _thumbNail.Dispose();
        }
        disposed = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created an http handler , from where I call the GetThumbnail() method like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using RMA.Shell;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace DemoApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ImageHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            byte[] buffer = null;
            string imgUrl = context.Request.Params["url"].ToString();             
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgUrl))
            {
                ShellThumbnail thumb = new ShellThumbnail();
                Bitmap bmp = thumb.GetThumbnail(context.Server.MapPath(imgUrl));                
                using (MemoryStream stram = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bmp.Save(stram, ImageFormat.Jpeg);                    
                    buffer = stram.ToArray();
                    bmp.Dispose();
                    thumb.Dispose();
                }
                HttpCachePolicy cachePilicy = context.Response.Cache;
                cachePilicy.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
                cachePilicy.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                cachePilicy.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                buffer = null;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have some doubts regarding this code

1. How this GetThumbnail() methods works? Is it use windows thumnail cache ie.thumb.db ? Or it generate the thumnail for each call?
2. Have any performance problem in using this COM API? Will it work for multiple concurrent http requests?

3.What is the difference between this with Windows API code Pack Shell implementation such as

```
ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(pathToYourFile);
Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
```

Which one is the better choice?

4.What will be the internal implementation ? Whether it using GDI+ or any other methods like IPP?

Please clarify

Answer (score 3):

Don't understand why you are doing all that COM mess when there are easy and clean managed solutions for resizing an image:

1. [Image.GetThumbnailImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) - downside of this method is low quality of re-sized images
2. [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) - open source image resizing component, very good thumbnail quality

Comment: I have to achieve better performance . I found this method generates thumbnails faster than any other methods

Comment: Actually, you're just adding overhead to the underlying WIC calls. Windows Explorer and the Thumbnail interface use the WIC API. [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net) lets you use the same WIC API without all the hassle and memory leaks through the [WicBuilder plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/wic).

Comment: It's not the default because it requires full trust, and because WIC is only server-safe on Windows Server 2008 R2 and higher. Your approach, also, should never be used on Windows Server 2008 R1.